# Retrieving an integer in the beginning of a string in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of test items, in the form of this:

```
8;SLEEP_MODE 
15;KWP_CHKSUM 
20;OS_SW_ID
```

I need to get the integer, the number at the beginning of the string, to store in a variable to use in an AJAX call. 
I first used the [0] parameter on the string, only to realize that was just stupid. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
parseInt('8;SLEEP_MODE', 10);
```

Don't forget the second argument (i.e. the radix) which tells the numeral system in which you want to parse your number. If you don't, you will sometimes get weird results like a conversion into the octal system (if your number starts with a leading 0).

**EDIT:** Using `split` prior to the parsing is right but unnecessary here, because `parseInt` will stop when it encounters non-digit characters.

Answer (score 5):

You can split the string into an array

```
var str = '8;SLEEP_MODE';
var arr = str.split(';');

// arr[0] is 8 
// arr[1] is SLEEP_MODE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a split first, eg.

```
"8;SLEEP_MODE".split(';')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` will extract the number for each line.

e.g.

```
 parseInt('8;SLEEP MODE') // = 8
```